# How to apply a formula to an entire Excel column using a keyboard missing its END key

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, worksheet-function

I have a keyboard with a trackpad that's missing some of the normal keys available on a full-sized keyboard (among them <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd>).

Also, there are 30,000 rows in the sheet and dragging the corner of the cell down the length of the column takes too long. It scrolls for minutes, and I have to create many formulas.

**Is it possible in the formula itself to say that it applies to the entire column?**

I want to the formula for this new column to grab the first two characters of another column:

```
=LEFT(E1|2)
```

Is there a way to specify "column E" rather than Cell E1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Supposing you want to put the formulas in column F*

I would try in this way:

1. write your formula on F1 (so the first cell will contain `=LEFT(E1,2)` )
2. select and copy the cell containing the formula (F1)
3. select the entire F column (click with your mouse on the column letter on top)
4. finally paste-special/formula and your formula will be in the entire F column (even a simple paste should do)

Comment: Thanks for paste-special. It works.  I can accept your answer in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

Select a cell in a column in your table that has values filled in all the way down to the bottom row of your table (if there is such a column), hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd>, which will jump you to the bottom row.

Then move over to the column where you want to fill the formula down, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> to select all the cells from there up.

If you have a header row or something that you don't want to copy into all those cells, hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> to contract the top of the selection down to the first cell with the formula you want to copy.  Then select "*fill down"* in the editing panel.

**Note:** This is if you only want the formula filled in down to the lowest row you are actually using - if you want the formula filled into the entire column, follow the copy and paste suggestion by danicotra.

Answer (score 2):

1. Enter your formula in the first row.
2. Arrow over into the column E.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>. If E has any blanks, you'll have to push this a few times to get to the last row with data.
4. Arrow over back to your formula column (in the last row).
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>. This will select all the cells above, including the top row that includes the formula you entered.
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to fill the formula throughout the selection.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to put the formula into Column `F`:

- Type `F1:F30000` into the Name Box (to the left of the Formula Bar)
  and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This will select that range.

  [image]
- Type `=LEFT(E1, 2)` …

  [image]

  … and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
  (***not*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

  [image]

That’s it.